# Bootstrap row extends beyond encompassing columns

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have been attempting to replicate Quora's design in Bootstrap when I encountered following problem. On every question page of Quora, say [this one](http://www.quora.com/What-are-some-of-the-mind-blowing-facts-about-Roger-Federer), there is a left sidebar. So for the first section (titled 'Want Answers'), I have a following structure:

```
<div class="col-lg-2">
    <div id="left-sidebar">
        <div id="want-answers">
            <p><small>18 WANT ANSWERS</small></p>
            <hr>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3"><img src="img/350x350.gif}" alt="" width="32px" height="32px"></div>
                <div class="col-lg-3"><img src="img/350x350.gif}" alt="" width="32px" height="32px"></div>
                <div class="col-lg-3"><img src="img/350x350.gif}" alt="" width="32px" height="32px"></div>
                <div class="col-lg-3"><img src="img/350x350.gif}" alt="" width="32px" height="32px"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3"><img src="img/350x350.gif}" alt="" width="32px" height="32px"></div>
                <div class="col-lg-3"><img src="img/350x350.gif}" alt="" width="32px" height="32px"></div>
                <div class="col-lg-3"><img src="img/350x350.gif}" alt="" width="32px" height="32px"></div>
                <div class="col-lg-3"><img src="img/350x350.gif}" alt="" width="32px" height="32px"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /#want-answers -->
```

Left sidebar is 2 columns wide. Now, as the image displays, each row (horizontal highlighting) extends `want-answers` div (vertical blue highlighting). Why is so? Shouldn't row encompass the full width of encompassing `col-lg-2` div?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is a problem but try closing out your image tags like this: `<img src="img/350x350.gif}" alt="" width="32px" height="32px"/>`
in your code there is no trailing slash.

A large portion of achieving what you are looking for will have to do with overriding default padding and margins that bootstrap applies to rows and or columns. I was able to contain the images and center them with the following modifications:
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/67znscex/)

CSS:

```
#left-sidebar {
text-align:center;
background:#ccc;
}
.min-width {
min-width:153px;
}
#want-answers {
background:#f1f1f1;
min-width:153px;
width:100%;
text-align:center;
}
.no-marg-pad {
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
.img-line {
background:#000;
width:100%;
min-width:153px;
}
.img-padding {
padding:0;
margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="left-sidebar" class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 no-marg-pad min-width">
<div class="row no-marg-pad">
    <div id="want-answers" class="col-xs-12">
        <p><small>18 WANT ANSWERS</small></p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row no-marg-pad">
    <div class="img-line">
        <div class="col-xs-3 img-padding">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="img/350x350.gif}" alt="" align="center" width="32px" height="32px" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 img-padding">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="img/350x350.gif}" alt="" align="center" width="32px" height="32px" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 img-padding">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="img/350x350.gif}" alt="" align="center" width="32px" height="32px" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 img-padding">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="img/350x350.gif}" alt="" align="center" width="32px" height="32px" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row no-marg-pad">
    <div class="img-line">
        <div class="col-xs-3 img-padding">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="img/350x350.gif}" alt="" align="center" width="32px" height="32px" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 img-padding">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="img/350x350.gif}" alt="" align="center" width="32px" height="32px" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 img-padding">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="img/350x350.gif}" alt="" align="center" width="32px" height="32px" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 img-padding">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="img/350x350.gif}" alt="" align="center" width="32px" height="32px" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

One other thing you may want to look at is defining the column width for small and medium size screens as well e.g. `col-sm-2 col-md-2`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you have any custom CSS for `#want-answers` or `#left-sidebar`, but one problem is that 4-32px images would usually extend beyond the width of the `col-lg-2`. Change them to `img-responsive` so they shrink as needed..

```
<div class="col-lg-3">
   <img src="//placehold.it/350" alt="" width="32px" height="32px" class="img-responsive">
</div>
```

http://codeply.com/go/OtSvmYQfcX